# Returning UIImage in block code

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I am using this code to return an image:

```
- (UIImage *)loadThumbnailForImageForUser:(int)userID inFolder:(int)folderNumber withFileName:(NSString *)fileName ofSize:(NSString *)size{

    NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMAGE%@%d", fileName, folderNumber]];

    [DropBlocks loadThumbnail:@"" ofSize:@"s" intoPath:filePath completionBlock:^(DBMetadata* metadata, NSError* error){

    }];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    return img;
}
```

The image returned is always nil. This is because the completionBlock is called later. Is there anyway to solve the issue and return the image?

Comment: You can use some 3d-party framework like SDWebImage (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which add convenient categories on `UIImageView`, for example `- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually handle this problem is to use a delegate pattern:

```
@protocol ImageLoadingProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void) imageLoaded:(UIImage*) image;

@end
```

In your image loader header:

```
__weak id<ImageLoadingProtocol> delegate;
-(void) initWithDelegate:(id<ImageLoadingProtocol>) delegate;

//or

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ImageLoadingProtocol> delegate
```

In your block:

```
[DropBlocks loadThumbnail:@"" ofSize:@"s" intoPath:filePath completionBlock:^(DBMetadata* metadata, NSError* error){
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [_delegate imageLoaded:img]; 
}];
```

And in the class that creates your image loader:

```
imageLoader = [[ImageLoader alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

//or

//imageLoader.delegate = self;
```

Then when the block is finished your class will receive a message `imageLoaded:` and you should implement a method to handle it:

```
-(void) imageLoaded:(UIImage*) image
{
    //Here is where your image is usable.
}
```

---

Here's another solution using blocks:

```
- (UIImage *)loadThumbnailForImageForUser:(int)userID inFolder:(int)folderNumber withFileName:

-(NSString *)fileName ofSize:(NSString *)size completionBlock:(void( ^ )( UIImage* image )) completionBlock
{
    NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMAGE%@%d", fileName, folderNumber]];

    [DropBlocks loadThumbnail:@"" ofSize:@"s" intoPath:filePath completionBlock:^(DBMetadata* metadata, NSError* error)
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        completionBlock(image);
    }];
}
```

**Caveat:** Watch out for syntax issues and memory management issues, I didn't write this in an IDE

Comment: I when for the second method. The app crashes on completionBlock(img);

Comment: To call it I did: [storeManager loadThumbnailForImageForUser:userID inFolder:folderNumber withFileName:fileName ofSize:size completionBlock:nil];

Comment: This is because I am returning the whole thing again: + (UIImage *)loadThumbnailForImageForUser:(int)userID inFolder:(int)folderNumber withFileName:(NSString *)fileName ofSize:(NSString *)size{
    DropBoxManager *storeManager = [DropBoxManager sharedInstance];
    return [storeManager loadThumbnailForImageForUser:userID inFolder:folderNumber withFileName:fileName ofSize:size completionBlock:nil];
}

Comment: If the completion block your passing is `nil`, what do you think it'll do on completion? Next, using the method I have there, you should have two completion blocks now.. look carefully. You *can* do it with one, but make sure you know what you're doing with blocks first.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a return and an asynchronous block. Either ensure the image is available before calling or, and this is the preferred option, add a completion block to the method and call that, supplying the image as a parameter. Then you can call the block either immediately if the image is already available or later when it is made available by the inner block.

Comment: You are mistaken when you say you can't use return and a completion block. It is completely possible to have a method return immediately then also call a completion block when its asynchronous task completes. The use case would be to return a loading image of an ImageView, then in the completion block have the requested image passed as a parameter.

Comment: @atreat a fair point, it is possible for a slightly different requirement.